# Firebase in android showing error while adding dependency to android studio 2.1.2

Tags: android, firebase

[image]

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

I have added this too in app dependency, but its showing error.

Comment: Geeks please help me out. i am new to firebase

Comment: Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0, this is what showing as error

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'
```

add this in dependencies under app gradle

and this under build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomand you using in your dependencies the last version of Firebase. At the moment the last versions is `11.0.4`.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
```

You need to do this change for all your dependencies existing in your build.gradle file.